# Mysql: Duplicate key error with autoincrement primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **table 'logging'** in which **we log visitor history**. We have 14 millions pageviews in a day, so we **insert 14 million records in table** in a day, and traffic is highest in afternoon. From somedays we are facing the problems for **duplicate key entry 'id'**, which according to me should not be the case, since **id is autoincremented field** and we are **not explicitly passing id in insert query**. Following are the details

```
logging (MyISAM)
----------------------------------------
| id                 | int(20)         |
| virtual_user_id    | varchar(1000)   |
| visited_page          | varchar(255) |
| /* More such columns are there */    |
----------------------------------------
```

Please let me know what is the problem here. Is keeping table in MyISAM a problem here.

Comment: What unique keys else do you have on that table? And do you have triggers on that table?

Comment: Concurring queries may be your case (so you need to post more details|)

Comment: What's the maximum ID in the table currently (SELECT MAX(id) FROM logging)?

Comment: @juergend Only id is unique key

Comment: @AlmaDo What more should I tell, please let me know?

Comment: @TimBurch Maximum id now is 180029247

Comment: How exactly are the records inserted (SQL, please)?

Comment: Problem is most likely in your code. MySQL is well prepared for concurrency with auto_increment. If you want alternative suggestions, you'll need to provide more details on this "log" and its use.

Comment: @TimBurch Records are logged into the file and inserted from there one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1: size of your primary key**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

The max size of an INT regardless of the size you give it is 2147483647, twice that much if unsigned.
That means you get a problem every 153 days.

To prevent that you might want to change the datatype to an unsigned bigint.
Or for even more ridiculously large volumes even a unix timestamp + microtime as a composite key. Or a different DB solution altogether.

**Problem 2: the actual error**

It might be concurrency, even though I don't find that very plausible.
You'll have to provide the insert IDs / errors for that. Do you use transactions?

Another possibility is a corrupt table.
Don't know your mysql version, but this might work:

```
CHECK TABLE tablename
```

See if that has any complaints.

```
REPAIR TABLE tablename
```

**General advice:**

Is this a sensible amount of data to be inserting into a database, and doesn't it slow everything down too much anyhow?
I wonder how your DB performs with locking and all during the delete during for example an alter table.

The right way to do it totally depends on the goals and requirements of your system which I don't know, but here's an idea:

Log lines into a log. Import the log files in our own time. Don't bother your visitors with errors or delays when your DB is having trouble or when you need to do some big operation that locks everything.

Comment: The amount of records should never be a problem (at least not that amount). Have been on sites where +50.000 inserted records per minute were normal, mysql as well. OP should consider 1) Do I really need an autoincremental id? What is that good for, is a timestamp not what we need? 2) Do I need to write to db constantly? For what purpose. Why not use a simple logfile, flush to that and make a script insert the records to the database log table once a day, once per hour or similar?

Comment: In my experience (~2M log entries per day, 10k average row size) MyISAM performs very well. I haven't run into any concurrency/locking or performance issues. The only issue so far is having enough disc space...

Comment: I saw another SO question where the asker turned out to have another script that did some auto-increment logic itself that caused the trouble. max(id) + 1. Probably not the case, but a possibility worth eliminating...

Comment: @Arnout Looking at your answers I think there is some problem with my script only. Will let you know the problem. Thanks